# Como pular todos breakpoints sem removê-los?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, debug, breakpoints

Existe algum atalho/configuração para ignorar todos os *breakpoints* sem necessariamente deletá-los do código?

Comment: Pode desabilitar e depois habilitar de volta. Ali no menu debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menu `Debug` -> `Disable All Breakpoints`

Fora isso, só apagando ou em alguns casos não deixando entrar onde tem *breakpoints* com <kbd>F10</kbd> ou pode encerrar a execução do método corrente com <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> o que pulará os *bps* ainda existentes nele, mas não fora dele.

[image: Disable All Breakpoints]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).